# how to get last relevant values from column in new column based on condition SQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get last certain value based on some condition in new column.

Sample data:

```
UID GID OMD  Prev_OMD Date

1    g1  bb   null    Jan 1
1    g2  bb   bb      jan 2
1    g3  bb   bb      jan 2
1    g4  tc   bb      jan 5
1    g5  of   tc      jan 10
1    g6  bb   of      jan 10
2    g1  tc   null    jan 11
2    g2  bb   tc      jan 14
```

I am stuck at writng sql query at below condition.

Tried out query till above condition

```
select uid, gid, omd, lag(omd,1) over (partition by uid order by date) as prev_omd , date
from table1
```

Below Result based on condition:

if  `omd` column value changed from `bb to any other text` for particular uid then get me last `bb` date for `current omd` row
but if `uid changed` and `row doesn't start` with `omd = bb` then `add null` in `new date` column else same row date

Here at line 4, `omd value is changed to tc`, then in new date last bb date should come and should be for all row till row with `omd = bb comes again`.

Expected Data:

```
UID GID OMD  Prev_OMD Date    New Date

1    g1  bb   null    Jan 1   Jan 1
1    g2  bb   bb      Jan 2   Jan 2
1    g3  bb   bb      Jan 2   Jan 2
1    g4  tc   bb      Jan 5   Jan 2
1    g5  of   tc      Jan 10  Jan 2
1    g6  bb   of      Jan 10  Jan 10
2    g1  tc   null    Jan 11  Null
2    g2  bb   tc      Jan 14  Jan 14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  t1.UID,
  t1.GID,
  t1.OMD,
  LAG(t1.OMD, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.UID ORDER BY t1.Date) AS Prev_OMD,
  t1.Date,
  CASE 
    WHEN t1.OMD = 'bb' THEN t1.Date
    WHEN LAG(t1.OMD, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.UID ORDER BY t1.Date) = 'bb' THEN 
      MAX(CASE WHEN t2.OMD = 'bb' THEN t2.Date END) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.UID, grp ORDER BY t1.Date)
    ELSE NULL
  END AS New_Date
FROM 
  table1 t1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT 
    UID,
    GID,
    OMD,
    Date,
    SUM(CASE WHEN OMD = 'bb' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY UID ORDER BY Date) AS grp
  FROM 
    table1
) t2 ON t1.UID = t2.UID AND t1.GID = t2.GID AND t1.Date >= t2.Date
```

Comment: could you please explain the logic behind?

Comment: hope this helps! - subquery `t1` to calculate `Prev_OMD` column using `LAG` -- subquery `t2` to calculate `grp` column(assigns a group number to each row based on the consecutive bb values in the OMD column for each UID) -- uses `CASE` to check if the current OMD value is not bb `and` the previous OMD value is bb (In this case -- uses `LAG` again to get the last Date value where OMD was bb for the current UID and grp) -- If current OMD value is bb(returns the current Date value -- else returns NULL)

Comment: i think your query will miss the cases like in `expected data` line 5, it will give null date to those cases

Comment: `SELECT  t1.UID,  t1.GID,  t1.OMD,  LAG(t1.OMD, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.UID ORDER BY t1.Date) AS Prev_OMD,  t1.Date,  CASE  WHEN t1.OMD = 'bb' THEN t1.Date WHEN LAG(t1.OMD, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.UID ORDER BY t1.Date) = 'bb' THEN       MAX(CASE WHEN t2.OMD = 'bb' THEN t2.Date END) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.UID, grp ORDER BY t1.Date) ELSE NULL  END AS New_Date FROM  table1 t1 LEFT JOIN (  SELECT     UID, GID, OMD, Date, SUM(CASE WHEN OMD = 'bb' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY UID ORDER BY Date) AS grp FROM table1) t2 ON t1.UID = t2.UID AND t1.GID = t2.GID AND t1.Date >= t2.Date`

Comment: You're correct (it doesn't handle the case where the OMD value changes from 'bb' to a new value and then back to 'bb' again for the same UID) -- I added a subquery to calculate a grouping variable grp that increments each time the OMD value is 'bb' for each UID -- in `CASE` that calculates the New_Date column -- I added a check to see if the previous OMD value was 'bb' -- If it was, I look for the maximum date where the OMD value was 'bb' within the same grp as the current row (within the same sequence of 'bb' values for the same UID)

Comment: can you pls update the answer?